# How to add custom fields in Low Stock report in Magento?

Tags: php, e-commerce, magento

I want to add Cost price and selling price fields in low stock report in magento.
I've attached a screenshot of low stock report page, here I want to add cost price and selling price fields next to "Stock Qty field". How can I add these custom fields in low stock report.? Could anyone tell me the steps to create custome fields in low stock report?

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do override of `_prepareColumns` method `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Product_Lowstock_Grid` classn add another column like:

```
$this->addColumn('price', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Price'),
        'width'     =>'215px',
        'align'     =>'right',
        'sortable'  =>false,
        'filter'    =>'adminhtml/widget_grid_column_filter_range',
        'index'     =>'price',
        'type'      =>'number'
    ));
```